# How to change content of <p> based on <div> name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am currently creating a web application.One of the function is to allow the users to create a div and assign a label to it which will be added to the class.The label name will then be displayed at the side based on the div's class name.Problem is I want to change the label name when I change the 's class name.I am unable to change the label for just one  if i have multiple divs.

I am using event.target to get the clicked  but if clicked on 2 divs separately,both are still selected and both class name will change.

```
//assign label and display it on the sides
$("#boxContain").click(function (event) {
console.log(event.target.nodeName);

$("#labels").on("change", function () {
    var modal = document.getElementById('lblList');
    if ($(event.target).attr('name') == null) {
        var e = document.getElementById("labels");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        console.log(strUser);

        var btn = document.getElementById("submitLbl"); //get submit btn
        btn.onclick = function () {
            event.target.setAttribute('name', strUser); //set the div name to the label
            $(event.target).addClass(strUser);


            var p = document.createElement("p");
            $(p).text(strUser);
            $(p).attr('id', strUser);
            $(p).attr('class', 'lbl');
            $(p).addClass(strUser);
            $("#existingLbl").append(p);
            modal.style.display = "none";

            $('#labels')[0].selectedIndex = 0;

        }

    } else {
        event.target.removeAttribute('ondblclick');
    }
});

});
//Edit labels
function edit(e) {
var classname = e.className.split(' ')[4];
return classname;
};
$('#createBoxBtn').click(function () {
$('.box').click(function () {
    var currentLbl = edit(this);
    console.log(currentLbl);
    var element = this;
    $('#editLblBtn').on('click', function () {
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = "none";
        var modal = document.getElementById('lblList');
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
        var btn = document.getElementById('submitLbl');
        var edit = document.getElementById('editLbl');
        btn.style.display = "none";
        edit.style.display = "block";
        modal.style.display = "block";
        $('#labels').on('change', function () {
            var list = document.getElementById("labels");
            var newLbl = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
            $(edit).on('click', function () {
                var p = document.getElementById(currentLbl);
                if ($(p).attr('id') == currentLbl) {
                    $(p).text(newLbl);
                    $(p).removeClass(currentLbl);
                    $(p).addClass(newLbl);
                    $(p).attr('id', newLbl);
                    $(element).removeClass(currentLbl);
                    $(element).addClass(newLbl);
                    $(element).attr('name', newLbl);
                    $('#labels')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                } else if ($(p).attr('id') == "Copyof" + currentLbl) {
                    $(p).text(newLbl);
                    $(p).removeClass(currentLbl);
                    $(p).addClass(newLbl);
                    $(p).attr('id', 'Copyof' + newLbl);
                    $(element).removeClass(currentLbl);
                    $(element).addClass('Copyof' + newLbl);
                    $(element).attr('name', newLbl);
                    $('#labels')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }); //end of edit
        }); //end of #labels
        span.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        };
        edit.onclick = function () {
            modal.style.display = "none";

        };
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        };
        $('#labels')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    }); //end of #editLblBtn
  }); //end of .box

}); //end of #createBoxBtn
```

When I edit the label,the div's classname AND name should change to a new label and the corresponding p tag should change as well.What should I do to achieve this?Is there any way to clear the data stored in event when I click on different elements?

Comment: You should specify the div, `$('#div-id p').text('your text')`

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar but the p is not in the div.It is displayed separately from the div.

Comment: Then you should add extra attribute to initialize the p of div

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar I did that and it didnt work.As i have stated above,when i click on one div to edit.Then click another div to edit.Both will be changed rather than just last selected div.